# How to view sequence details with a SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

As you know, we can view the details of a sequence by using '\d' command.
I would like to know if there is a way to get these information with a SQL query so that I can view the details for all sequences in PostgreSQL database.

Eventually, the left 'Column' will be displayed horizontally like we see normally when we use a sql statement.

```
postgres=# \d next_empno
         Sequence "public.next_empno"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value        
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | next_empno
 last_value    | bigint  | 8000
 start_value   | bigint  | 8000
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 0
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | f
```

Comment: You can always `\ds *.*`, but otherwise, use the `information_schema`

Comment: I didn't know about information_schema. It has everything I need to check. Thank you.

Comment: A good way to find those queries is to start `psql` with the `-E` (echo hidden) option. It will show you exactly what queries psql uses internally

Comment: Oh. Really wonderful!. Awesome! With that option, we can find the internal queries very easily. Cool.

Comment: Though note that `psql` uses the PostgreSQL catalogs directly.  Unlike `information_schema` these are subject to change from version to version and are not standard across database engines. Where possible, you should prefer the `information_schema`.

Comment: Thanks for good advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.sequences.

There documentation is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-sequences.html).

Comment: It would have been nice if you actually put an example query. I don't find this any more useful than the first comment on the OPs question.

Comment: @PanamaJack . . . This answer was 33 minutes before the first comment.

Answer (score 13):

To view the DDL of the sequence, use this

```
select * from information_schema.sequences where sequence_name='<your_sequence_name_in_lower_case>'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL for view 'sequences':

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences
```

Comment: the better question is how to list them with their currval()